# Prove the equality by induction

Tags: calculus, summation, induction

I need to prove the following equality by induction: $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^nx^i\right)^{} =\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$ for every x except $$x\neq 1$$
Could anyone give me a hint about this? Thank you

Comment: Is that equation true for every $x$ (except 1)?

Comment: "Inequality" ?   More to the point, is it true for $n=1$?  I think you have a typo in your satement.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} x^i = x^{n+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n} x^i$$